# How to set overflow-x: auto for nested div?

Tags: html, css

```css
#create-summary {
  width: 200px;
  height:150px;
  margin-top:20px;  
  overflow-x:auto;
  overflow-y:auto;
}

.lv2 {
    margin-left:15px;
}

.lv3, .lv4, .lv5, .lv6{
    margin-left:15px;
}

#create-summary  div {
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="create-summary">
    <div class="lv1">
        1. Title1
        <div class="lv2">1.1. Title1.1</div>
        <div class="lv2">
            1.2. Title1.2
            <div class="lv3">1.2.1. Title1.2.1</div>
            <div class="lv3">
                1.2.2. Title1.2.2
                <div class="lv4">
                    1.2.2.1. Title1.2.2.1
                    <div class="lv5">1.2.2.1.1. Title1.2.2.1.1</div>
                </div>
            <div class="lv4">1.2.2.2. Title1.2.2.2
                <div class="lv5">1.2.2.2.1. Title1.2.2.2.1</div>
                <div class="lv5">1.2.2.2.2. Title1.2.2.2.2
                  <div class="lv6">1.2.2.2.2.1 Title1.2.2.2.2.1</div>
                </div>
            </div>
                
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see the 
class "lv6" and class"lv5" is not display correctly even I set overflow-x:auto.
How to set overflow:x auto to make it correctly?

Comment: is "right" to have to scroll to the right?

Comment: What does **right** mean? How do you want it formatted?

Comment: edit the question again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like that?

```css
#create-summary {
  width: 180px;
  height:200px;
  margin-top:20px; 
  overflow-x: auto; 
}

.lv2 {
    margin-left:15px;
}

.lv3, .lv4, .lv5, .lv6{
    margin-left:15px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="create-summary">
    <div class="lv1">
        1. Title1
        <div class="lv2">1.1. Title1.1</div>
        <div class="lv2">
            1.2. Title1.2
            <div class="lv3">1.2.1. Title1.2.1</div>
            <div class="lv3">
                1.2.2. Title1.2.2
                <div class="lv4">
                    1.2.2.1. Title1.2.2.1
                    <div class="lv5">1.2.2.1.1. Title1.2.2.1.1</div>
                </div>
            <div class="lv4">1.2.2.2. Title1.2.2.2</div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is there any way can have scroll bar on the bottom?Because if I have a lot of level , i will need to set overflow many times.

Comment: On the bottom of what element?

Comment: on the bottom of class " create-summary"

Comment: You can set `white-space` for the childrens and `overflow-x` for the parent.

Comment: I really appreciate and it really help me.Now I am going to check what is white-space: nowrap; on my own. XD

Comment: You can check it here: [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp). Glad that helped!  :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the whole div larger, Or you can set overflow-x to scroll.

```css
#create-summary {
  width: 250px;
  height:200px;
  margin-top:20px;  
}

.lv2 {
    margin-left:15px;
}

.lv3, .lv4, .lv5, .lv6{
    margin-left:15px;
}

#create-summary  div {
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="create-summary">
    <div class="lv1">
        1. Title1
        <div class="lv2">1.1. Title1.1</div>
        <div class="lv2">
            1.2. Title1.2
            <div class="lv3">1.2.1. Title1.2.1</div>
            <div class="lv3">
                1.2.2. Title1.2.2
                <div class="lv4">
                    1.2.2.1. Title1.2.2.1
                    <div class="lv5">1.2.2.1.1. Title1.2.2.1.1</div>
                </div>
            <div class="lv4">1.2.2.2. Title1.2.2.2</div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add CSS `white-space: nowrap;` to lvl elements.

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer to this question! Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, because a code dump with no context doesn't explain how or why the solution will work, making it difficult for the original poster (or any future readers) to understand the logic behind it. Please, edit your question and include an explanation of your code so that others can benefit from your answer. Thanks!